# linphone library compile issue xcode 7.3 MAC OS El Capitan v10.11.4

Tags: ios, macos, sip, voip, linphone

I have download linphone open source VoIP project from git. 
Follow steps that given in [link](http://www.successmonkey.co.nz/blog/building-linphone-for-ios#disqus_thread) but i have stuck on one steps

**Link host strings to simulator SDK**

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/strings /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strings
```

->I have checked below path 
"/usr/bin/strings" and found that 'strings' not found and also another path not work '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strings'

->When command run at that time it fail with below reason

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strings': No such file or directory
```

-> On Build I have received below output.

```
 *******************************************************************************
This makefile is deprecated. Please see README.md for compilation instructions. Here are some equivalents:
Equivalent of make is: cd ../../ && ./prepare.py && make
Equivalent of make enable_gpl_third_parties=no is: cd ../../ && ./prepare.py -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=NO && make
Equivalent of make enable_debug=yes is: cd ../../ && ./prepare.py -d && make
Equivalent of make enable_i386=yes is: cd ../../ && ./prepare.py all && make
Equivalent of make enable_zrpt=yes enable_opus=yes enable_ffmpeg is: cd ../../ && ./prepare.py -DENABLE_ZRTP=YES -DENABLE_OPUS=YES -DENABLE_FFMPEG=YES && make
*******************************************************************************
```

Below Link I have referred

1) https://libraries.io/github/mfrager/linphone-iphone

2)
 https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone/blob/master/README.macos.md

3) https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2015/10/01/how-i-got-el-capitain-working-with-my-developer-tools/

Answer (score 0):

->**I have checked below path "/usr/bin/strings" and found that 'strings' not found and also another path not work**

Firstly you have to generate `strings` file at this path anyhow.
After that please check that whether your Xcode in Applications have name as `Xcode.app` or `Xcode7.3.app`

---

```
This makefile is deprecated. Please see README.md for compilation instructions.
```

For this error, it may occur because you are trying

```
$ make all
```

this command
Instead try this:

```
./prepare.py && make
```

For more info, regarding home-brews, etc, follow correctly(as you mentioned you'r following it):
[building linphone-sdk](http://www.successmonkey.co.nz/blog/building-linphone-for-ios)

Also give all the **permissions(rwxrwxrwx)** to linphone-sdk directory and all other related files

I've followed this for iOS project.
Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

For HomeBrew make sure run:

brew update then
brew doctor

to double check. Also refer to http://www.successmonkey.co.nz/blog/building-linphone-for-ios

After the dependencies are installed run ./prepare.py and make to compile everything (had a easy fix in submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/src/basemsfactory.cs) then use Xcode the build the final application.